# XAML Parse Exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

ive searched and searched the answer eludes me still. here is my code

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace GTA_5_Guide
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        //Constructor
        public MainPage()
        { 
            //Loads the page onto the screen           
            InitializeComponent(); //This is were the error is thrown

        }

    }
}
```

the error thrown is a "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll"

everything was working fine till I decided not to use a web page I had found in my project anymore noe it throws this error

Comment: You should post the MainPage .xaml

Comment: ...working fine till I decided not to use a web page... did you delete MainPage.xaml? :)

Comment: The code you given doesn't give any clue to what is happening, You need to show the Markup `Xaml` especially the area where you removed the WebPage.

Answer (score 0):

9 times out of 10 this is usually just the designer file not inheriting the same Type.

Make sure your MainPage root XAML control is in-face `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage...`